# problems with DateTimeField filter in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Help please me) 
I have error "[u"'data_date' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]" and don't know how resolve it.

my models.py

```
class Data(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeignKey(Main)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    data_date = models.DateTimeField(['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'])
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'])
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.description
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.data_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

my views.py

```
def index(request, onsuccess='/', onfail='/login/'):       
    today = date.today()
    data_data=timezone.now()
    formatted_datetime = formats.date_format(data_data, "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT")
    problems_filter = Data.objects.filter(main_id=1).filter(data_date__range=['data_date', 'end_date']).order_by('-data_date').order_by('priority')[:101]
#    problems_filter = Data.objects.filter(main_id=1).order_by('-data_date').order_by('priority')[:10]
```

When i'm use the commend string, it's work fine.

Example format:
 28 | 1 | admin | hi | 2014-05-01 00:41:00 | 2 | 2014-06-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have ignored `seconds` portion from the input string to convert to `datetime`.

```
data_date = models.DateTimeField( ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'] )
end_date  = models.DateTimeField( ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'] )

+---------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| input_date_string   | its_format        | what_you_tried |
+---------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| 2014-05-01 00:41:00 | %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S | %Y-%m-%d %H:%M |
| 2014-06-01 00:00:00 | %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S | %Y-%m-%d %H:%M |
+---------------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

Change accordingly for both `data_date` and `end_date` fields.

```
data_date = models.DateTimeField( ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'] )
end_date  = models.DateTimeField( ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'] )
```

**Refer to**:  [***DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS)

Default:

```
(  
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'  
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'  
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'  
    '%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'  
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'  
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'  
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'  
    '%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'  
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'  
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'  
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'  
    '%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'  
)
```